# Consultation on iOS project work with version control

Tags: ios, bitbucket

I'm starting to work on a project of a mobile application for iOS with swift with a partner and need to work together this project. We have some doubts about how to work together on the project and would like to see you give us tips to work it properly. We want to work with bitbucket.

Comment: Git & Bitbucket is a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips:

- Use xibs, not storyboards due to merging.
- Avoid working both on a xib file
- Add a propper .gitignore file to your repository
- When merging xcodeproj files try to merge all changes (otherwise your in for a ride :-))
- Use Cocoapods or another library dependency manager